# Android studio not showing light bulb(yellow bulb) in flutter project for somewhere like wrap a widget with another widget

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I use android studio for developing my projects, but it has been a while the studio not showing lightbulb(yellow bulb) for suggestion like wrap widget with another widget or modifying.

I tested many solution and of course used from Alt + Enter, also set true check for Soft-Wrap, but it still doesn't work.

**my android studio version is:** Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart, io.flutter

**my dart and flutter version is:** Flutter 3.0.2 • channel stable • Dart 2.17.3 • DevTools 2.12.2

Answer (score 2):

**First method**

In android studio go to Settings >> Editor >> Intentions and check Dart check box and click ok

**Second method**

Double click on shift button and write intentions and check Dart check box and click ok

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Goto

`File->Invalidate cache / Restart`

Still not working? restart your PC.

Comment: I did both, but it not work!

Comment: and make sure power saver mode is turned off,

file -> power saver mode

Comment: I did it but it didn't work again...(It is worth mentioning, my os is mac)

Answer (score 0):

Delete **.idea** folder  at the root of your project then File->Invalidate cache / Restart

Answer (score 0):

**For Android Studio**

1. Double click on **SHIFT** button
2. Write **Intentions**
3. Check the **DART** checkbox and click on apply and then save

That's it